# random score as a function in elasticsearch nest.net

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to achieve the following structure using Nest.Net and not seeing any way to accomplish it.  I can add another Filter as a function, but I just want to drop in a random score so I can achieve weighted random results.  My work around at the moment is to just build my query, serialize it to a string, then plop in my random_score syntax, then create a SearchDescriptor and use the QueryRaw method.

Note the random_score inside the functions bracket.  This snippet is taken from ElasticSearch's documentation on Random Scoring.  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/random-scoring.html

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "filter": {
        "term": { "city": "Barcelona" }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": { "term": { "features": "wifi" }},
          "weight": 1
        },
        {
          "filter": { "term": { "features": "garden" }},
          "weight": 1
        },
        {
          "filter": { "term": { "features": "pool" }},
          "weight": 2
        },
        {
          "random_score": { 
            "seed":  "the users session id" 
          }
        }
      ],
      "score_mode": "sum",
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the current Nest.NET code that you have so far?

Comment: You just want to see how I'm building the function score currently?  The FunctionScoreQueryDescriptor only takes in IFunctionScoreFunction's as an option.  RandomScoreFunction does not implement IFunctionScoreFunction and so cannot be added.

Comment: Has been already fixed in NEST 2.x. Not sure what about backport to 1.x, always worth to [ask](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues).

Comment: @odyth - there's an open issue for this for 1.x - https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1559

Comment: @odyth just pushed changes to the `1.x` branch to address this. You'll be able to build from source, will be up on myget soon (https://www.myget.org/gallery/elasticsearch-net-legacy) and also on nuget once a cut is made